# An isomorphism restriction is also isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Let's take $\phi: F \longrightarrow F'$ a field isomorphism. Then we know that the mapping 
$$\psi: F[x] \longrightarrow F'[x],$$

$$ f(x):=a_nx^n+...+a_0\mapsto \psi(f(x)):=\phi({a_n})x^n+...+\phi(a_0) $$ 
is an integral domain isomorphism.

Let, now, $p(x)\in F[x]$ an irredicible polynomial over $F$ and $p'(x)=\psi(p(x))\in F'[x]$.

We want to show that the restriction mapping 
$$\sigma:=\psi|_{\langle p(x) \rangle}:\langle p(x) \rangle  \longrightarrow \langle p'(x) \rangle$$
$$g(x)\mapsto \sigma (g(x)) = \psi(g(x))$$ 
is again an integral domain isomorphism.

- If $g_1(x)=a(x)p(x)\in \langle p(x) \rangle$ and $g_2(x)=b(x)p(x)\in \langle p(x) \rangle$, with $a(x),b(x)\in F[x]$, then

$$\sigma (g_1(x)+g_2(x))=\sigma(p(x)(a(x)+b(x))=\psi(p(x)(a(x)+b(x))=\psi(p(x)a(x))+\psi(p(x)b(x))=\psi(g_1(x))+\psi(g_2(x))=\sigma(g_1(x))+\sigma (g_2(x))$$
and similarly for $``\cdot"$.

- $\ker \sigma =\{g(x)=a_nx^n+...+a_0: \sigma g((x))=0_{F'}   \}=\{0_{F'} \}$
- And at last the image $\text{Im}\sigma=\{\psi (g(x)):g(x) \in \langle p(x) \rangle   \}=\langle p'(x) \rangle$.

So we have an isomorphism between these two integral domains.

Is this syllogism right?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by an _integral domain isomorphism_ for $\langle p(x) \rangle$ and $\langle p'(x) \rangle$? The subset $\langle p(x) \rangle$ of $F[x]$ is an ideal, but itself not a ring (unless $p$ is constant). The same goes for $\langle p'(x) \rangle$.